# generating .docx with aspos

Tags: java, md5, aspose

I'm trying to convert a file into .docx using [aspose](http://www.aspose.com/)

However, even though the file generated in Microsoft Word looks identical  to the MD5 of the generated file, it is different each time I run the same program.
Is there a way to ensure that file integrity using aspose?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
System.out.println(DigestUtils.md5Hex(bytes));
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

Document doc = new Document(bis);
doc.save("newFile.docx");
bis.close();

bytes= FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("newFile.docx");
System.out.println(DigestUtils.md5Hex(bytes));  //<-- generates a MD5 that is different each time I run the program...why??
```

My question is, is there a way to ensure we get identical MD5 hash after each run?

Comment: MD5 hashes are unique per file. you can't just have duplicates, thats the whole point of MD5 hashes. I believe this has nothing to do with Aspose nor java

Comment: @polisha989 everytime I run the same script for the same input. the MD5 generated (on the second print out) is different. basically, MD5 must be same everytime

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words mimics the same behavior as MS Word does. If you re-save your input document multiple times using MS Word, the MD5 hex value for each output document will be different.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: yeah, we ended up saving things as PDF. that solved the problem and managed to get right results.